# Migrating a working .each( .. .change()) to .each( .live("change...")) don't works jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a list of inputs that are loaded some at document ready and others are loaded dynamically. I need to sum all of them because I need to  check that all of them doesn't sums more than 99.

The problem is that with .live() I can't get it working but it works with .change().

```
/* this works */
$(".percentage").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".percentage").each(function() {
            sum += $(this).val();
        });
        alert(sum);
    });
});

/* this don't */
$(".percentage").each(function() {
    $(this).live("change keyup focus click keydown", function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".percentage").each(function() {
            sum += $(this).val();
        });
        alert(sum);
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how `live` works. `live()` attaches a handler to all current, and future elements in the DOM that match the given selector. What you're doing is that for each element currently in the DOM with a class of "percentage", you're binding an event to all current a future elements with the class of "percentage", so each element's ending with numerous events bound to it.

Try:

```
$('.percentage').live('change keyup focus click keydown', function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $(".percentage").each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    });

    alert(sum);
});
```

Furthermore, `val()` will return a string, so you'll have to do:

```
$(".percentage").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This code works with the first input.percentage I've on the HTML. The problem is that I'm adding others with JavaScript and if I load more, this ones fails. :(

Comment: @udexter: Are they definitely being added with the right classes and so on? Maybe show the scriptbeing used to add them?

Comment: @udexter: As Chris said, can we see the script that adds the new elements to the DOM? The code I've provided should work for this.

Comment: You too were right. It was my ajax loaded content that didn't have the class percentage assigned... sorry for that. Thank you! :)